# Laravel 5.5 Array Diff com bug?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou desenvolvendo em Laravel 5.5 e Php 7.1.9 e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Tenho a seguinte tela de Checkboxes e ao marcar qualquer um dos campos, o `arraydiff` do `Laravel` insiste em retornar o valor da diferença incorreto, ou seja, se eu marcar qualquer um dos checkbox da imagem ele retorna `1 => 2` como diferença vejam a imagem.

Print da Tela
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorno utilizando a função ArrayDif do Laravel
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho do código gera o CheckBox

```
{{-- percorrendo a tabela para exibir os checks--}}
@foreach($users as $keys => $dados_users)                                                
        {{-- se o resto da divisão for par será exibido na coluna A --}}                           
        @if(!($keys % 2))
            <tr class="">    
                <td></td>             
                <td></td>   
                <td></td>      
                <td></td> 
                <td></td>                                                           
                <td class="">                                   

                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="user_id[]"  id="user_id" value="{{ $dados_users->id }}"> {{ $dados_users->name }}</p>             
                    <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="user_id_desmarcados[]" id="user_id_desmarcados" checked value="{{ $dados_users->id }} "></p>              
                </td>                                                           
        {{-- se não será exibido na coluna B --}}                                                                                             
        @else                                                
                <td></td>        
                <td class="">                                                                                                                                                                      
                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="user_id[]"  id="user_id" value="{{ $dados_users->id }}"> {{  $dados_users->name  }}</p>  
                    <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="user_id_desmarcados[]" id="user_id_desmarcados" checked value="{{  $dados_users->id }} "></p>                         
                </td>                                                        

            </tr> 
        @endif                                                           

{{-- finalizando o foreach --}}
@endforeach
```

Codigo do Controller com o ArrayDiff (Laravel)

```
public function store(PerfisuserRequests $request)
    {
        // recebendo todos os dados do formulário    
        $dataForm = $request->all();   


        // repassando o valor do Id 
        $id_perfis = $dataForm['perfis_id'];

        /*************************** Verificando os dados que foram Marcados na Inclusão ****************/
        /***********************************************************************************************/

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array Diff
        $collection = collect($dataForm['user_id_desmarcados']);

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array Diff
        $collection2 = collect($dataForm['user_id']);    

        // realizando a verificação atráves do Array Diff
        $diff = $collection->diffKeys($collection2);

        // aqui será retornado a diferenca entre os Arrays
        $diferenca = $diff->all();

        dd($diferenca);
```

Para Efeito de Comparação (afinal não estava funcionando da forma que eu queria), resolvi usar a função direta do php para chamar o `array_diff` e para minha surpresa o retorno foi favorável, ou seja, consegui o retorno que precisava vejam os exemplos.

Print do retorno com o Check 1  marcado 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print de Tela com o Check 2 Marcado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho do Codigo do Array_Diff

```
 $teste = array_diff($dataForm['user_id_desmarcados'], $dataForm['user_id']);

    dd($teste);
```

Por isso pergunto:

Isso seria um Bug no array diff do Laravel 5.5 ou estou fazendo algo errado?

Existe algum problema em não utilizar a função nativa do `array diff` no laravel?

Comment: Você queria a diferença e extrair os valores, está confuso. a função pra igular é `diff` no caso!

Comment: sim! precisava da diferença! o que quis mostrar é que o array_diff do laravel não está funcionando corretamente! o diff estava sendo utilizado

Comment: Você não usou certo e o `array_diff`não é do Laravel é do PHP! use `$collection->diff` esse que é para você utilizar... inclusive faz a mesma coisa usando arra_diff!

Comment: acho q voce não entendeu o codigo... sim eu sei q o array_diff é do php .. mas o laravel possui um metodo próprio..  a primeira vez eu utilizei o collection...

Comment: eu entendi sim, e o Laravel tem uma classe `Collection` para trabalhar com isso, eu sei tudo isso, mas, não tem bug nenhum, o que pode estar acontecendo é uma confusão sua, uma coisa que eu gostaria de ti dizer poderia reformular a pergunta dando exemplo de como deseja o resultado e de como não está dando certo, isso está muito confuso se puder, o exemplo é minimo dando a entender, do jeito que está você não está usando `$collection->diff` se está usando `$collection->diffKeys` e isso é o que estou vendo na sua pergunta